# Why does Vue.js use the single-word tag <component>, which violates their own style guide?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So, Vue.js has its own style guide, which clearly states (in the "essential" section) that [component names should be multi-word](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential) to prevent "conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since all HTML elements are a single word".

Yet they use the `<component>` tag for [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). I couldn't find `<component>` in the list of existing HTML tags.
Does this mean that if one day HTML adopts a `<component>` tag, Vue.js will try to parse them and break?

Please clarify.

Comment: I think this may be best directed to their forums. https://forum.vuejs.org/

Comment: i will post there too, thank you for suggestion

Comment: Also, `template`, `slot` and `transition`.

Comment: I also posted on the Vue forums, hoping to discuss/elaborate the reasoning behind this rule: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-vue-multi-word-component-names/128485   Hopefully someone joins in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Vue.js is doing it's best to stick to the W3C standard.

[Relation to Custom Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Relation-to-Custom-Elements)

> You may have noticed that Vue components are very similar to Custom
> Elements, which are part of the [Web Components Spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebComponents/). That’s because
> Vue’s component syntax is loosely modeled after the spec. For example,
> Vue components implement the [Slot API](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/Slots-Proposal.md) and the is special attribute.
> However, there are a few key differences:
>
> The [Web Components Spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebComponents/) has been finalized, but is not natively
> implemented in every browser. Safari 10.1+, Chrome 54+ and Firefox 63+
> natively support web components. In comparison, Vue components don’t
> require any polyfills and work consistently in all supported browsers
> (IE9 and above). When needed, Vue components can also be wrapped
> inside a native custom element.
>
> Vue components provide important features that are not available in
> plain custom elements, most notably cross-component data flow, custom
> event communication and build tool integrations.

### Other reading

[HTML Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents)

> The <COMPONENT> element serves as a container to identify an HTML
> Component.  It is not required; however, in many instances it may be
> useful in order to help the consumer of the HTML Component determine
> that an event was in fact fired from this particular component .  The
> <COMPONENT> element serves to bind together the properties, methods
> and events as well as to provide a location for the identifier of this
> HTC.

Which also specifies <template> and <slot>

[Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

> HTML templates: The <template> and <slot> elements enable
> you to write markup templates that are not displayed in the rendered
> page. These can then be reused multiple times as the basis of a custom
> element's structure.

I don't know about <transition>.